# Importing a File Containing Two Objects from Blender into Unity Leads to a Single GameObject Not Two

Tags: blender, obj, import

I have two separate objects in a Blender file (say a cube and a sphere). Unity import this file (OBJ type) as a single gameObject which is not want I want. I want cube and sphere to be two separate gameObjects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use separate OBJ files for this.

You could also import .blend files directly: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-ImportObjectBlender.html